# Permanently grant permission to /dev/snd for all users?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, audio, devices

After reboot

```
~$ arecord -l
arecord: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

and

```
$ sudo arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC892 Alt Analog [ALC892 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And if I do

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /dev/snd
```

the `arecord` is starting to see devices without `sudo`.

Unfortunately, after reboots there are no permissions again.

How to make devices readable for normal users by default?

Comment: Why don't you use PulseAudio? Not sure why you're trying to make your life harder. Check the group ownership of ALSA devices and add your user(s) to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was to add myself to `audio` group. This was the group owner of `/dev/snd/*`